# Stripe Connect With Parse in java

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jsp-tags

I faced a problem to connecting with parse database after parse migration. When I tried the following code in my controller class

```
Parse.initialize(
    new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .applicationId("myAppId")
        .server("http://myServerUrl/parse/")
        .build()
);
```

I used parse4j library file can any suggest the other library

Comment: What is your actual problem? Any errors? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yes, currently i used parse4j library but i can't invoke the above code likeParse.initialize(
    new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .applicationId("myAppId")
        .server("http://myServerUrl/parse/")
        .build()
); i want to one thing what is getApplicationConext().